# In gmail, how to filter messages to support@mycompany.com but not if they are also sent to me@mycompany.com

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm receiving quite a lot of emails for support in my inbox that I want to filter out.

A couple of weeks per year I'm on stand-by. In those weeks I need to be able to receive those emails sent to support. The rest of the year, I'm not interested in support mails.

I tried creating a filter to filter out all emails sent to support@mycompany.com. But that also filters out emails sent to both me and support. Naturally I do want to receive messages sent to me, even if they are also sent to support.

So I want to create a filter that will filter out any emails sent to support, but not those that are also sent to me.

Comment: Maybe creating two filters - one that archives support@mycompany.com emails and one that brings it back from archive if it is addressed to you?

Comment: Only add yourself to receive mails that are addressed to support for a few weeks a year?

Comment: Creating 2 filters is an option, but I'd rather do it with one filter if possible.

@Seth I would if I could do that myself, but support needs to edit those settings and they don't like to have to change who gets the emails every week.

Comment: Try using the "Has the words" and "Doesn't have" fields instead of the "To" field. That'll let you do an "A and not B" search/filter. You'll end up with something like this: `support@mycompany.com -{you@mycompany.com}`. (If those addresses appear in a body or a signature, that might trip you up, but this should get you pretty close.)

Comment: @elloco999 I assume that your question was originally downvoted because it was posted to the wrong site. Now that it's on the correct site, that downvote has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ale. I posted my question at superuser because a similar question at stackoverflow was locked with the message it should have been posted at superuser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter on `to:(support@mycompany.com) -to:(me@mycompany.com)` should do it. Immediately archive, send to trash, whatever.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect solution to my problem! But how do I enter this in gmail as a filter? If I enter this in the to field of the filter creation form it doesn't work.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. You can enter it in the search bar and create a filter from there.